# django-chronograph script wont run from cron job or manually due to permissions issue

Tags: python, django, linux, cron, debian

I've created a custom management command as a py file, in the usual place.

chronograph is installed in the right place and syncd ok.

I've created the cron job as the following

```
* * * * * /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/bin/chronograph -e /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/bin/activate_this.py -p /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/website
```

ive also tried the following, as i think it may be correct but not whats in the documentation

```
* * * * * /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/bin/chronograph -e /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/bin/activate_this.py -p /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/website/manage.py cron
```

I've added the manage.py cron because its what you run to tell the chronograph function to look for jobs that need running. if im in my virtual env and i run manage.py cron it works and the job runs.

both jobs are failing to run, but when i try to run them manually, as su or my user, they fail due to permissions denied. not sure what permission they're referring to. anyone come across this before?

Comment: Try adding &>> /tmp/chrono.log to the end of one of the lines and tail -f that file. That should give you some more info.

Comment: doesn't need the ampersand. also add -l to the cron line to get more verbose output as detailed by the script...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer for this was that chronograph.sh has been superseded by chronograph. despite this supposedly being able to activate an env, it wasn't doing it early enough to import argparse which as far as i can tell isn't inbuilt to python 2.5 but is in 2.6. then its just down to getting the right combination of arguements for the chronograph script, which for reference is a -p and an -e but not an -s.

also i had to run the script as root but targetting the script inside the users virtualenv.

finally i also had to add site paths for packages directory to the chronograph script as it couldnt find argparse until i did that.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this comes in handy for issue you have with file permissions. [File permission basics](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html)

Have you tried running the cron job as the appropriate user/service?

To edit crontab entries of other Linux users, login to root and use -u {username} -e as shown below.

```
root@dev-db# crontab -u otheruser -e
@monthly /home/otheruser/fedora/bin/monthly-backup
00 09-18 * * * /home/otheruser/ubuntu/bin/check-db-status
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a virtual environment:
Included is a script called `chronograph.sh`.  Copy this file
to your project directory.

```
cp chronograph.sh ~/virtualenvs/webbricks/chronograph.sh
```

You need to open up this script and modify the path to your virtual environment's `activate`
script::

```
$PROJECT_PATH"/home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/bin/activate"
```

Make sure that this file is executable and then update your `crontab` to execute the
script.

```
chmod a-x chronograph.sh
```

Then:
    crontab -e

```
* * * * * /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/chronograph.sh /home/shofty/virtualenvs/webbricks/website
```

Make sure that you pass `/path/to/your/project` to the script as the first argument.
This should ensure that `cron` shouldn't have problems finding your project directory.

Comment: in the path to the activate statement, you dont have the file suffix on. is that right?

Comment: chronograph.sh has been superseded by chronograph. despite this supposedly being able to activate an env, it wasn't doing it early enough to import argparse which as far as i can tell isn't inbuilt to python 2.5 but is in 2.6. then its just down to getting the right combination of arguements for the chronograph script, which for reference is a -p and an -e but not an -s

Answer (score 0):

Is it os permission denied or are your receiving a 403? If it is a 403 I think is most likely caused by Django's CSRF protection.  If your script is posting to a particular view, make sure to mark it as [csrf_exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views)

If the permission denied is at the file system / operating system level then I don't really know.